# Ackerman function

Tags: ackermann-function

I have a very elementary question:
[here](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/1/1952/files/2014/01/LongFinSeq98-2f0wmq3.pdf)

on the page 7, 4th line

why

$$ A_{k+1} (n+1) = A_k (A_{k+1} (n))$$

Is it trivial or do we need induction ?

Comment: It follows directly from line $1$ of page $7$: $A_{k+1}(n) = A_kA_k\cdots A_k$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde But the r.h.s. on the 1st line of page 7 has $1$ as an argument; the displayed formula has $n$. Could you be more explicit ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm adding bounty for you, please reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the way the definition is phrased.

A common way of defining the Ackermann function is this one:

(1) $A(0,n)=n+1$

(2) $A(k+1,0)=A(k,1)$

(3) $A(k+1,n+1)=A(k,A(k+1,n))$

If you rewrite $A(k,n)$ as $A_k(n)$, line (3) becomes

$A_{k+1}(n+1) = A_k(A_{k+1}(n))$

Your source uses an alternative style of definition, starting
with $A_1$ and $A_{k+1}(n) = A_k\circ\cdots\circ A_k(1)=A_k^n(1)$.
Starting from there, you can also obtain

$$
A_{k+1}(n+1) = A_k^{n+1}(1)= A_k(A_k^n(1)) = A_k(A_{k+1}(n))
$$

Comment: Still is something wrong there You write in the last but one line $$A_{k+1}(n)=A^n_k(1)$$ and on the last line $$A_{k+1}(n+1)=A^n_k(1).$$ So $$A_{k+1}(n)=A_{k+1}(n+1)$$ and this is strange.

Comment: yes, in the last line, the part after the first '=' should be shifted to match with the left side. I correted that now.